# Какие команды нужно прописать в командном окне (терминале), чтобы получить из .cpp файл статической библиотеки .lib

Tags: c++, консоль, g++

Во всех источниках рассказывается как это делать через Visual Studio, а я хочу понять как это пошагово работает -- через терминал. Использую компилятор g++. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста)

Comment: Создать объектные файлы, соединить их в библиотеку (кажется, в G++ нужны `g++ -с` и `ar`.

Comment: Файлы формата .lib создаются утилитами из инструментов vc++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC использует для статических библиотек расширение `.a`, не `.lib`.

1. Компилируете `.cpp`-файлы в объектные файлы `.o` командой `g++ -c 1.cpp` (получится `1.o`).
2. Объединяете несколько объектных файлов в `.a` командой `ar crs libX.a 1.o 2.o`.

Имя лучше начинать с `lib...`, потому что GCC при линковке (флагом `-l...`) подставляет этот префикс автоматически.

Перед вызовом `ar` я бы удалял старый `.a`-файл. Если этого не сделать и удалить/переименовать какие-то объектники, они не удалятся из `.a` и будет конфуз.

Comment: а в какой операционной системе вы хотите это сделать? @AlexPapa я так спросил, потому-что в линуксе знаю, а в винде не шарю..

Comment: @AlexGlebe В винде (на mingw) так же.